# Adding object to arraylist gives outofmemory in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, out-of-memory

I have the following code:-

```
protected void onPostExecute(JsonReader reader) {
            Person object=null;
            try {
                reader.beginObject();
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    String name = reader.nextName();
                    if (name.equals("results")){
                        reader.beginArray();
                        while (reader.hasNext()) {
                            reader.beginObject();
                            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                String id = reader.nextName();
                                if(id.equals("bioguide_id")){
                                    object=new Person();
                                    String bioguide_id=reader.nextString();
                                    object.bioguide=bioguide_id;
                                }
                                else if(id.equals("last_name")){
                                    String lastname=reader.nextString();
                                    object.lastname=lastname;
                                }
                                else if(id.equals("first_name")){
                                    String firstname=reader.nextString();
                                    object.firstname=firstname;
                                }
                                else if(id.equals("party")){
                                    String party=reader.nextString();
                                    object.party=party;
                                }
                                else if(id.equals("state_name")){
                                    String statename=reader.nextString();
                                    object.state=statename;
                                }
                                else if(id.equals("district")){
                                    if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL){
                                        reader.skipValue();
                                        object.district="NA";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        String district=reader.nextString();
                                        object.district=district;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                    reader.skipValue();
                                object.image="https://theunitedstates.io/images/congress/original/"+object.bioguide+".jpg";
                                personData.add(object);
                                //object.display();
                            }reader.endObject();
                        }reader.endArray();
                    }

                    else {
                        reader.skipValue();
                    }
                }reader.endObject();


            }
            catch (IOException e){
                Log.w("Error",e.getMessage());
            }

            ByState.display();
        }
    }
}
class Person{
    String bioguide;
    String image;
    String lastname;
    String firstname;
    String district;
    String state;
    String party;
}
```

Then I have the arraylist that I used in the above code as following:-

public static ArrayList personData = new ArrayList();

On running the above code I get the OutOfMemory error in Android.

Error:-

```
16 11:21:28.230 20236-20236/com.app.congress.congressapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.app.congress.congressapp, PID: 20236
                                                                              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 69748 byte allocation with 54912 free bytes and 53KB until OOM
                                                                                  at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
                                                                                  at com.app.congress.congressapp.ByState$GetAllStates.onPostExecute(ByState.java:112)
                                                                                  at com.app.congress.congressapp.ByState$GetAllStates.onPostExecute(ByState.java:49)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
11-16 11:21:28.770 20236-20248/com.app.congress.congressapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
11-16 11:21:29.850 20236-20248/com.app.congress.congressapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
11-16 11:21:29.850 20236-20248/com.app.congress.congressapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10(320B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 0 total 120ms
11-16 11:21:30.430 20236-20248/com.app.congress.congressapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
11-16 11:21:31.080 20236-20248/com.app.congress.congressapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
```

The error is shown in the line where I add the person object to the Array List. All I want is to set the variables in Person by parsing the Json and once its done add it to an arraylist of type person. So basically the arraylist should have collection of objects of type person created from Json data. I dont know where I ma going wrong. Please advise me.

Comment: You have used all but ~50KB of your 64MB heap. You are using too much memory. You need to determine where your memory is going and use less of it.

Comment: Thats what I am not able to figure out. I am just creating an arraylist of objects...there can be many objects because the json file has large amount of data...is there any way I can do it

Comment: Use a profiler to inspect the memory.

Comment: "there can be many objects because the json file has large amount of data" -- start by examining the JSON file and see how big it is. Bear in mind that many Android devices offer smaller heap sizes than does your test device. It is entirely possible that the right answer is to not load the entire data set into memory at one time. If, however, the file is fairly small, you might use logging or breakpoints to try to determine whether you have gotten into an infinite loop, infinite recursion, etc. that is causing you to use up available memory.

Comment: probably you need to give this line a thought: "personData.add(object);". if you stuff lots of thing in the memory then you will see this type of error. Do you really need to hold everything in memory? what are you going to do with personData after you finished parsing your JSON?

Comment: To display it in a listview

Comment: actually even if you want to show it in a listview, the screen can only show a portion of those data at a time. So better way is to store your data in a database and use CursorAdaptor to read it

Comment: Why is the arraylist static? The static list keeps everything alive for the whole lifetime of your application. It's a GC root